# Why does the pointer to a character equal its value?

Tags: c, pointers, character

I was looking at my friend's code and found something that looked like this:

```
char foo[2] ="f";

if(*foo =='f'){
    printf("%d",*foo);
}
```

I was wondering why this comparison evaluates true? I don't understand why the pointer to foo is the same as its value.

I understand that the standard thing to do would be to use strcmp for this kind of thing but was just wondering out of curiosity

Comment: `*foo` is not a pointer, it's pointer dereferencing, so it returns the value the pointer points to.

Comment: `*foo` is `'f'`, `*(foo+1)` is `'\0'`. Arrays are "pointer-like"; I don't know how the standard defines things precisely.

Comment: `*foo` is equivalent to `foo[0]` if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `*foo` is pointer dereferencing. Pointer itself is just `foo` and this one would not be equal 'f'.

Answer (score 1):

`foo` is an array, which degenerates into a pointer. So `foo` evalutes to an address

```c
printf( "%p\n", (void*)foo );  // Print an address.
```

`*foo` is a dereference of that pointer, giving the value to which the pointer points.

```c
printf( "%c\n", *foo );        // `f`
```

---

> I understand that the standard thing to do would be to use strcmp

`strcmp(foo, "f") == 0` is not equivalent to `*foo == 'f'` since the latter just checks the first character. However, `strncmp(foo, "f", 1) == 0` would be equivalent.

Comment: `strncmp(foo, "f", 1) == 0`, though, is equivalent (I think?).